# Given 2D array with marked cells, find duplicate shapes formed by those marked cells

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, multidimensional-array, shapes

Given a 2D array with cells which are marked and combined together forms different linear shapes, how would you identify duplicate shapes.

0010000100000000000000000000
0010000100000000000000000000
0011100100000100000000011100
0000000100000111111000000000
0010000111100100000000000000
0110000000000001111000000000
0010000100000000000000000111
0000000001000000000011110000
0000000001111110000000000000
0010000001000000000000000000

Here we have 3 duplicate shapes :
1
111111
1

111

1

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you think you understand what set of steps would be involved?

Comment: I don't see where just `1` is a duplicate shape and it looks like you're missing `1111`.  This also feels like a gimme the codes question, so please edit it to tell us what you have tried.

Comment: sry but i am clue less on this..

Comment: Somebody does not want to do his homework :-)

Answer (score 3):

Find all the shapes generated by connected `1`s by looping over the cells until you find a `1` and then use a flood fill algorithm to find the shape formed by all connected cells.  How you store the flood filled shape is up to you, but I'll assume you created a string representation of each one.  Now find the distinct strings using any of the jillions of methods that are out there for comparing strings.

Comment: Can you give me any good link for Flood fill algorithm please

Comment: @user1660982 just google it, there are plenty of good resources.  I'd have posted more information if you showed us something you have already tried.  If you're anxious about posting what you've tried because it didn't work, don't worry about it, that's why we're all on this site.  If you haven't tried anything at all, my answer should be enough to give you ideas to start a solution.